# Autoclose date range input shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I want the date picker to autoclose after a date is selected. I know how to do it when the daterangeinput is rendered directly in the ui but not when it is created in the server.

Here is my code.

```
library('shiny')

js_string <- "$('#dates input').bsDatepicker({autoclose: true});"

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsCode", function(message) { eval(message.value); });'))),
    includeScript("code.js"),
    fluidRow(
      column(4, 
             uiOutput(outputId = 'dateui'),
             verbatimTextOutput("datesOut")
      )
    )
  ), 
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dateui <- renderUI({
      dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"))
    })
    session$onFlushed(function() {
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'jsCode', list(value = js_string))
    })
    output$datesOut <- renderPrint({ names(session) })
  }
)
```

`$('#dates input').bsDatepicker({autoclose: true});` works well if the daterange is created in the ui directly as shown in following code. Besides this code also works well if I want to disable keyboard input with `$('#dates').attr('onkeydown', 'return false');`.

```
library('shiny')

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    includeScript("code.js"),
    fluidRow(
      column(4, 
             dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range")),
             verbatimTextOutput("datesOut")
      )
    )
  ), 
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$datesOut <- renderPrint({ input$dates })
  }
)
```

With the js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dates input').bsDatepicker({autoclose: true});
});
```

My question is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323255/disable-keyboard-input-in-daterange-shiny/49366932) I posted.

I also tried `$('#dates input').datepicker({autoclose: true});` but it does not work. I know that `$(document).ready(function() ...` cannot work as the code will be launched once the document is ready hence before the daterange is rendered.

**Edit:**

I also tried using `shinyjs` but it does not work either.

```
library('shiny')
library('shinyjs')

jsCode <- "shinyjs.changeDate = function(){
$('#dates input').bsDatepicker({autoclose: true});
$('#dates').attr('onkeydown', 'return false');
}"

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
    fluidRow(
      column(4, 
             uiOutput(outputId = 'dateui'),
             verbatimTextOutput("datesOut")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dateui <- renderUI({
      dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"))
    })
    session$onFlushed(function() {
      js$changeDate()
    })
  }
)
```

I am stuck here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

**Edit2:** Adding my session info

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinyjs_1.0 shiny_1.0.5 V8_1.5     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.4  R6_2.2.2        htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.4     curl_3.1       
 [6] yaml_2.1.18     Rcpp_0.12.16    digest_0.6.15   jsonlite_1.5    xtable_1.8-2   
[11] httpuv_1.3.6.2  mime_0.5
```

Comment: Maybe you should try shinyjs's package `hide()`

Comment: Using `shinyjs::hide()` I can hide the daterange input but not just the date picker without adding the `.datepicker()` which does not work right ?

Comment: I haven't worked with js strings, so I guess I don't know.

Comment: I an really stuck, I can't figure out why my code does not have the same effect when called with `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler`. I guess I'll have to dive into the links between js and shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but it works using JQuery:

```
            tags$head(
                tags$script(HTML("setInterval(
                      function checkContainer () {
                        if($('.datepicker-days').is(':visible')){ //if the container is visible on the page
                          $(function () {
                              $('td.day').click(function () {
                                $('.dropdown-menu').hide()
                              }); 
                            });
                          } else {
                            setTimeout(checkContainer, 50); //wait 50 ms, then try again
                          }
                        },
                      50  /* 10000 ms = 10 sec */
                      );"))
            )
```

All you need to do is add this to the tags$head function within `fluidpage` of your `ui`.

This works if the last user input is selecting the day.

If your `dateRangeInput` is limited to choosing the month, then all you have to do is edit `'.datepicker-days'` to `'.datepicker-months'` and change `'.td.day'` to `'.td.month'`. If you're limiting to a year; change `days` to `years` and change `day` to `year`.

The reason as to why it's hacky is because the JQuery script is being redeployed every 50ms so as to check if the `datepicker-days` class is visible...but it works.