# Disallow manual date entering

Tags: angular, devexpress

How can I set the widget to disallow entering dates manually? User should only be able to pick the date using the calendar.

The example form is here: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/Widgetsgallery/Demo/Form/CustomizeItem/Angular/Light/

The field I am referring to is the 'Hire date'.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29715698/13258211

Comment: It's hard to tell to whcih element apply the 'onkeydownn' biding. I tried on <dxi-item> and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the field 'acceptCustomValue' of the [editorOptions] to 'false'.