# how can i disable datepicker input text without disabling the calender

Tags: angular

i need to  prevent users from typing in the date picker text field

```
 <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-text" for="date">Date picker</span>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" name="datePicker" [(ngModel)]="datePicker">
 </div>
```

```
  minDate = '1980-10-28';
  maxDate = '2099-10-28';
```

Comment: Could this be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715655/html-5-input-type-date-disable-keyboard-input?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.